# Equivalent of R language function 'is.na' in MATLAB

Tags: r, matlab

Is there an equivalent function in MATLAB to R's `is.na`?

I'm trying to convert the following line of to code from R.

```
if(sum(is.na(u))>0 || sum(is.na(v))>0)
```

where `u` and `v` are vectors.

Comment: The function you're looking for is `isnan`.

Comment: @R Greg Stacy  I have this function in mind, R documentation says 'is.na' tests for missing values, and that means it is similar as looking for NANs in matlab using isnan?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a matrix in MATLAB, then all values are numerical, `NaN` or `+/-Inf`. If you simply want to identify which ones are `NaN` then you should use [`isnan`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isnan.html) like so:

```
if any( isnan(u) ) || any( isnan(v) )
```

Note, you could use [`sum`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html?s_tid=doc_ta) or [`nnz`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nnz.html) with a `>0` comparison as you've done in R, instead of using [`any`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html) as shown, but `any` is the appropriate function here for usability and code readability.

You mentioned in the comments that you want to check for 'missing' values. There is also a MATLAB function [`ismissing`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismissing.html) which will have the same behaviour as `isnan` for a double matrix. The behaviour is different for other variable types (e.g. cell arrays checking for `''`), see the linked documentation for details.